# How to use Bing Speech API with Bot Framework C#

Tags: c#, api, botframework, bing-speech

I want to use Bing Speech API with bot framework and I have downloaded a c# project from this link https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/bing/Speech-To-Text-Bot-using-db55e1d0

but in web.config it needs the following values to get the token:
 I tried with these values:

`<add key="BotId" value="YourBotId" />
 <add key="MicrosoftAppId" value="83da8d84-f5c0-488a-8ebf-1eb74f5437f8" />
 <add key="MicrosoftAppPassword" value="CHCvJpjoCKwukJHU2J30djc" />`

When I run the project with the values that I specified in MicrosoftAppId and MicrosoftAppPassword

The bot emulator throws the following error:

`-> POST 401 [conversationUpdate] 
[10:00:42] Error: The bot's MSA appId or password is incorrect. 
[10:00:42] Edit your bot's MSA info`

but I think I´m using the correct values.
I got the appID and Passwordsecret from https://apps.dev.microsoft.com and I also tried with the appID and Password provided from bot framework registration portal when I registered my bot.

I don´t know if it could be because I am not providing the key="BotId" but I don´t know where can I get that ID.

You would help me a lot if you download the project and tell me how to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to fill the `MicrosoftAppId` and the `MicrosoftAppPassword` when using the emulator.

Also, [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/CSharp/intelligence-SpeechToText) you will find another example of a bot using the `Bing Speech-to-Text` API.

And BTW, in case you require the AppId and AppPassword (e.g. when deploying the bot to `Azure`), the ones that you need to use are the ones that you got from the Bot registration portal

Comment: Your link is broken, can you re-share?